# ERROR: Could not resolve "worker_threads" during wrangler deploy to Cloudflare node.js application

Tags: node.js, deployment, cloudflare, wrangler

During wrangler deploy to Cloudflare node.js application, I get an error

```
ERROR: Could not resolve "worker_threads"

build/worker.js:42155:29:
42155 │     var { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
```

My wrangler.toml file

```
name = "my-worker"
main = "build/worker.js"
compatibility_date = "2023-07-05"
account_id = "01111111111111111"
node_compat = true

[triggers]
crons = [ "0 0 1 1 *" ]

[build]
command = "npm run build"
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "my-worker",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "build/worker.js",
  "node": "18.11.18",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cloudflare/workers-types": "^4.20230518.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.2.1",
    "wrangler": "3.1.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "wrangler dev",
    "build": "npx esbuild ./src/index.ts --bundle --platform=node --external:node:* --outfile=build/worker.js",
    "deploy": "wrangler deploy"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-inject": "^5.0.3",
    "@tsndr/cloudflare-worker-jwt": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "itty-router": "^4.0.14",
    "toucan-js": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

To fix the problem, I tried to install the polyfill https://github.com/ionic-team/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/
Change node version
Change version of "@cloudflare/workers-types"
Change version of "@types/node" and "ts-node"
Deleted and reinstalled the node_modules folder

Comment: To resolve this problem, you need to remove or refactor any code that relies on the "worker_threads" module. This module is specific to Node.js and is not supported in the Cloudflare Workers runtime.

Comment: @Alex Gordon thanks for the answer, it prompts some thoughts, I will think about reorganizing the code